# Drupal: hiding node titles

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

is there any option in the drupal settings to hide the node titles ?

I usually comment the code in my theme template, but I was wondering if I can do it from drupal back-end. (For all nodes, or some content-types.. (even better)).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Node titles are somewhat fundimental to drupal.

Removing via the theme is proably the best way to go for the front end of your site. You will need to change the default page title as well.

You can prevent people from having to enter node title with the [Automatic Nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) module.

But there are still pages like /admin/content which will show the node title.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from backend using views and specyfing what exactly you want to show.

Comment: I actually don't want to create a new view, but i just want to display a single node page without the title. This is easy to do in the theme template, I was just wondering if I can do it from Drupal settings directly.